# Not able to display an image in repeater control for [thumbnail images]

Tags: asp.net

i have  imgae path  in datatable[id, path]  now this  would  a  value like

```
ex: id   path
    1    F:\R&D\RD\RD\Images\a1.JPG;
    2    F:\R&D\RD\RD\Images\a2.JPG;
    3    F:\R&D\RD\RD\Images\a3.JPG;
```

now these  images  are in  size width*height (1018*768). now i need  to  convert these  images  into thumnail

caling the  function

```
**C_Thumbnails(100, "F:\R&D\RD\RD\Images\a1.JPG", "F:\R&D\RD\RD\Images]thum.jpg")**
public static void C_Thumbnails(int size, string FilePath, string ThumbPath)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(FilePath);

            try
            {
                int thumbHeight, thumbWidth;

                decimal h = image.Height;

                decimal w = image.Width;

                if (image.Height > image.Width)
                {

                    thumbHeight = size;

                    decimal tWidth = (w / h) * thumbHeight;

                    thumbWidth = Convert.ToInt32(tWidth);

                }

                else
                {

                    thumbWidth = size;

                    decimal tHeight = (h / w) * thumbWidth;

                    thumbHeight = Convert.ToInt32(tHeight);

                }
                System.Drawing.Image thumbnailImage = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                image.Dispose();
                thumbnailImage.Save(ThumbPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                image.Dispose();
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

like this   i am  coverting into  thumbnail image. but here i am   saving the thumbnail image  under  the path  **F:\R&D\RD\RD\Images\thum.jpg** .

so is there any way without saving the  thumbnail in the **disk**    and how to  bind the  new thumbnail image in the  repeater  control   and i need to  show  image there. but if once user  clicks on the  thumnail image a  orignal image  should pop up.

if any one  have  did  this  functionlity any where  let me know
  working on this  solution from past  2 days.
 any help  would  be greatly appreciated

**now after  changing code**
like  this

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string imageid = context.Request.Params["ImageID"];
        string thumbnail = context.Request.Params["thumbnail"];
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Image from Image where ImageID=" + imageid, connection);
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        string filePath = dr["image"].ToString();
        dr.Close();

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            //you have a problem 
            return;
        }
        if (context.Request.Params["thumbnail"] == "true")
        {
            //TODO: the thumbnail
            // Image thumbnailImage = originalImage.GetThumbnailImage to generate thumbnail then
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "image/" + format;
            thumbnailImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, imageFormat);
            thumbnailImage.Dispose();

        }
        else
        { //stream directly the image fromdisk
            System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filepath);
            const int ChunkSize = 10000;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[ChunkSize];
            long dataLengthToRead = fs.Length;

            while (dataLengthToRead > 0)
            {
                int lengthRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, lengthRead);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                dataLengthToRead = dataLengthToRead - lengthRead;
            }
            fs.Close();
        }
    }


}
```

in repeater control  i have added  this line  of code
  
                   ','_blank','toolbar=no,menubar=no'))" > '/> 
                 
   my thumbnail image is  not  displayed  still but once i click my thumbnail image i   am  able to see the entire image in new pop  up

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Photo Image Handler](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/desaijm/HTTPHandlersForImages11152005062705AM/HTTPHandlersForImages.aspx) to serve the pages from your disk to the clients.
Then in the repeater control

```
  <a href="ImageHandler.ashx?thumbnail=false&id='<%# Eval("ID")%>'>
       <img src="ImageHandler.ashx?thumbnail=true&id='<%# Eval("ID")%>' border='0'/>
  </a>
```

The ideea is not to pass in the actual path/name of the file, but the ID of the item you wish to view. Then the handler will:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context)
    {
         string filePath = //TODO: Get File Path from ItemID = context.Request.Params["id"]
         if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
         { 
             //you have a problem 
             return;
         }
         if(context.Request.Params["thumbnail"]=="true")
         {
             //TODO: the thumbnail
             // Image thumbnailImage = originalImage.GetThumbnailImage to generate thumbnail then
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ContentType = "image/" + format;
            thumbnailImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, imageFormat);
            thumbnailImage.Dispose();

         } else 
         {  //stream directly the image fromdisk
           System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filepath);
            const int ChunkSize = 10000;
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[ChunkSize];
            long dataLengthToRead = fs.Length;

            while (dataLengthToRead > 0)
            {
                int lengthRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, lengthRead);
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                dataLengthToRead = dataLengthToRead - lengthRead;
            }
            fs.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: thnaks  for  the replay i tried ur  code it is not  displaying  the thumbnal image  still   but when i click the   image  buton   but image is shown in new pop ip

Comment: there is a "TODO:the thumbnail" in the code.. just paste the code you were using before to generate the thumbnail,but this time save tumbnailImage to the Response's OutputStream instead of disk. It should work then